# Symfony Exception, DB query with controller and twig Template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a controller file and a twig template but the communication is disturbed.
The Exception is:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Error producing an iterator").

Either I still miss something in the controller file or something is wrong with the settings.

My Object is "ArticleCategory"
Controller:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Pimcore\Controller\Configuration\ResponseHeader;
use Pimcore\Model\Asset;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Pimcore\Model\DataObject\ArticleCategory;
use Zend\Paginator\Paginator;


class ContentController extends FrontendController
{ 
    public function testroot1Action(Request $request)
    {   
        $articleCategory = new ArticleCategory\Listing(); 
        $articleCategory->setOrderKey('date');
        $articleCategory->setOrder('DESC');

        $paginator = new Paginator($articleCategory);
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($request->get('page'));
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(5);
        var_dump($paginator);

        $this->view->content = $paginator;

    }
}
```

The Twig Template. The Exception comes from my for in loop. The iterate of "content" dosent work:

```
{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}
{% block content %} 


    {{ dump(content)}}

   {% for contents in content %}

        {{ dump(contents)}}        

    {% endfor %} 

{% block content %}
```

Is there somthing more to do or is somthing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

it should be :

```
{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}         

   {% for content in contents %}     

       // here you have access to a singular content object

    {% endfor %} 

{% block content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah no that isnt it!
It seems that my Listing is empty!

```
$articleCategory = new ArticleCategory\Listing();
```

Hm i will test it later more Thx

Answer (score 0):

That is possible because you get a Laminas\Paginator\Paginator which is Iterateable (to use in foreach) when it has results.

When you first access an element, it is loaded by your ORM (like Doctrine) and when there is an error, like an invalid entry in the database, which could not be converted to the PHP Entity, this error appears.